# Convert HTML Template to PDF using itext7 with dynamic header & footer

Tags: java, html, css, pdf, itext7

I've tried to use the below HTML template to convert it to PDF using iText7 but both header and footer are not binding to their intended position.
[used example](https://plnkr.co/edit/lWk6Yd?preview)
I'm trying to avoid @Page header and footer properties since I'm trying to accomplish fitting dynamic content in both sections with extended space more than 3 rows in each.

iText code and result:

```
ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();
//properties.setFontProvider(fontProvider);
properties.setMediaDeviceDescription(new MediaDeviceDescription(MediaType.PRINT));
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter("out.pdf");
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
pdf.setTagged();
PageSize pageSize = PageSize.LETTER;
pdf.setDefaultPageSize(pageSize);

OutlineHandler outlineHandler = OutlineHandler.createStandardHandler();
properties.setOutlineHandler(outlineHandler);

//html template (templateOutput)
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(templateOutput, pdf, properties);
byte[] pdfData = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
pdf.close();
```

[image: The second page without header and footer]
[image: First Page]

Please any suggestions to resolve the issue?
Thank you

Comment: You should use `@page` media selector and `running` elements in CSS to exclude an element from the main flow and include it into a header

Comment: Thank you...I used running elements previously & it worked fine. However, the content in both sections limited to only one line. I'm trying to accomplish fitting at least 3 lines in the header and footer sections dynamically. Any alternatives?

Comment: you can use running elements with block-level elements (div, paragraphs) perfectly fine and it should give you the desired result

Comment: I've tried it with div...still the content shows only 2 lines although I've added 3 lines and specify the div height as 15% of the page.

Comment: you should also specify the height of the header, it's specified with `margin-top` CSS declaration: `@page { margin-top: 200px; }`

Comment: Please demonstrate with an example. I've tried with the margin but the whole section still won't appear. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of HTML that is correctly processed by `pdfHTML` and multiline header is displayed fully at the top of the page as expected:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        #header {
            position: running(header);
        }

        @page {
            margin-top: 100px;
            @top-center {
                content: element(header);
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="header">Header line 1<br/>Header line 2<br/>Header line 3</div>

<p>Content of the page</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Page looks as follows in the resultant PDF:

[image: result]